# How to create composite UNIQUE constraint in FluentNHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I know that I can `Map(x => x.GroupName).WithUniqueConstraint()` for a single property.

But how do create a composite unique constraint in fluent nHibernate (where the unique constraint operates on the combination of two columns)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the latest version that I have used, it is`UniqueKey("KeyName")`that does this.

```
Map(x => x.Something).UniqueKey("KeyName");
Map(x => x.SomeOtherThing).UniqueKey("KeyName");
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me.  The key is created, but it only includes the first field.

Answer (score 8):

Use `SetAttribute` in your mapping file like so:

```
Map(x => x.Something).SetAttribute("unique-key", "someKey");
Map(x => x.SomeOtherThing).SetAttribute("unique-key", "someKey");
```